# Mostrar o recorrer todos los datos de un procedimiento almacenado en sql server en un textView

Tags: java, sql, android, sql-server, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código en Android Studio (JAVA) para ejecutar un procedimiento almacenado en mi BD en SQL Server. Se ejecuta correctamente, pero no se muestran todos los datos que arroja el sp.

Código en Android Studio.

```
                    CallableStatement cStmt = conn.prepareCall("exec crear_usuario_pam @accion='olvido_clave',@usuario= '" + usr + "', @I_grabar=1");
                    //cStmt.registerOutParameter("passs", Types.VARCHAR);

                    cStmt.execute();
                    final ResultSet rs = cStmt.getResultSet();

                    while (rs.next()) {
                        String pass = rs.getString(1);

                        requireActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            txtPass.setText(pass);
                            btnAsignar.setEnabled(false);
                            btnAsignar.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "Transaccion OK!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        });
                    }

                    conn.close();
```

Resultado arrojado en SQL Server al ejecutar el SP manualmente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la aplicación solo me muestra el primer dato arrojado por el sp. "SinReporte". El nombre y lo demás que esta abajo ya no se muestra.
¿Qué puedo hacer para mostrar todo lo arrojado por el procedimiento almacenado?

Comment: Hola @Alexeni Cruz, creo que tu pregunta no debería estar aquí, si ejecutas el procedimiento en SSMS y te devuelve los datos que tu esperas creo que el problema está en tu código que no "captura" los datos devueltos adecuadamente

Comment: tu sp está devolviendo cuatro consultas , prueba hacerles un union all a los 4 resultados